# How do I combine fputs without throwing error

Tags: c, fputs

I'm having trouble on my assignment below. Whenever I try to combine the `fputs` argument in one line, error will show too much argument in `fputs`.

What I'm trying to do is to create an output in every child file that include time and also text in **one line** but the codes below giving me the output like this:

```
Tue May 15 16:48:00 2018
Message sample
```

Is there any way so that the output can be like

```
Tue May 15 16:48:00 2018  Message sample
```

Thank you.

```
fputs(asctime(timeinfo),writetext);
fputs(str,writetext);
fputs("\n",writetext);
```

Comment: Remember that [`asctime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/asctime) adds a newline in the string it produces. Also remember that the string returned by [`asctime`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/asctime) can be modified like any other string (like for example changing the newline to the string terminator).

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works when i change it to  time_str[strlen(time_str)-1] = '\0';

Answer (score 0):

You can open your file in r+ mode. After this line of code

```
fputs(asctime(timeinfo),writetext);
```

put this line of code

```
 lseek(fileno(writetext),SEEK_CUR,-1);
```